# Display "only X left threshold" and stock status on category view

Tags: magento2, category, stock, view

I'm new to Magento(2) and I'm trying to display Stock Status, stock count, and quantity field in category view like in product view.
I don't know where to get theses values and where to put it...
I'm using magento 2.2.10 and I'm using the default luma theme

I found that if i comment some containers in `catalog_product_view.xml` at rootFolder/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout, it disable it from the product page, so i suppose that i need to copy this code to some other file but i can't figure it out...

Thanks in advance for your help guys

Where I want to add information:
[image: My category view here, where i want to add some informations]

Where I want to copy values into category view:
[image: My Product View, where I want to copy values into category view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display qty on category page, there are 2 methods either create your custom module and call its block on both places or add code directly using `$ObjectManager`.

> This method is not recommended but since you need some quick and easy
>   solution that is why I am giving it here :

```
<?php
    $ObjectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $StockState = $ObjectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');

    echo $StockState->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
 ?>
```

for adding on listing page Go to your theme folder `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` file and add below code where you want to show it i.e underneath product name etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you for your response @Supravat_M

I just tried your solution by pasting this piece of code into "/var/www/html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml" but when I refresh the cache all products disappear ..

I tried in "/var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml" and there it does nothing at all.

I restored the files to their original format but my problem remains ...

Thank you all the same for your help ..